# Почему не удается спозиционировать адаптивный блок по центру внизу контейнера?

Tags: html, css, css3, позиционирование

Есть у меня адаптивный блок с шириной в зависимости от надписи. Как его расположить точнехонько внизу по центру блока `breadcrumbs`, чтобы он оставался все время адаптивным. С помощью марджинов  мне удалось расположить так, как того хочу, но заметна разница в 1px между браузерами хромом и сафари (пробовал и пиксели и em). Кажется что такое 1px, но на сайте это сразу бросается в глаза. Как можно это поправить? Смотрю в сторону абсолютного позиционирования, но тогда получается беда с адаптивностью.. Набросал [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/12824/).

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://dnevniki.ykt.ru/upload/appearance/2014/3/h_10133_5687.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.breadcrumbs {
  padding: 9px 0;
  background-color: #f2f4f5;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.trail-end-table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.trail-end-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trail-end-left {
  background: url(http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1510/e4/e8ee16bf4502.png) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.trail-end {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/20/0f05f5fc4613.jpg) repeat;
  min-width: 240px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trail-end-right {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/94/ab81953cb1a9.jpg
) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
      <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
        <div class="trail-end-table">
          <div class="trail-end-wrapper"><span class="trail-end-left"></span><span class="trail-end">Личный кабинет</span><span class="trail-end-right"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ .container-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поставьте `width` на `.trail-end-wrapper`. Например я поставил `width: 276px;`. Посмотрите так

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://dnevniki.ykt.ru/upload/appearance/2014/3/h_10133_5687.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.breadcrumbs {
  padding: 9px 0;
  background-color: #f2f4f5;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.trail-end-table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.trail-end-wrapper {
  width: 276px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.trail-end-left {
  background: url(http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1510/e4/e8ee16bf4502.png) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.trail-end {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/20/0f05f5fc4613.jpg) repeat;
  min-width: 240px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trail-end-right {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/94/ab81953cb1a9.jpg
) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
      <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
        <div class="trail-end-table">
          <div class="trail-end-wrapper"><span class="trail-end-left"></span><span class="trail-end">Личный кабинет</span><span class="trail-end-right"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ .container-->
</div>
```

Или так

```css
.breadcrumbs {
  background: url("http://dnevniki.ykt.ru/upload/appearance/2014/3/h_10133_5687.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
.breadcrumbs {
  padding: 9px 0;
  background-color: #f2f4f5;
}
.mad-breadcrumbs i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.trail-end-table {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.trail-end-wrapper {
  width: 276px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.trail-end-left {
  background: url(http://s013.radikal.ru/i323/1510/e4/e8ee16bf4502.png) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.trail-end {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold";
  font-size: 18px;
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/20/0f05f5fc4613.jpg) repeat;
  min-width: 240px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.trail-end-right {
  background: url(http://s020.radikal.ru/i715/1510/94/ab81953cb1a9.jpg
) no-repeat;
  height: 48px;
  width: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
      <div class="mad-breadcrumbs">
        <div class="trail-end-table">
          <div class="trail-end-wrapper"><span class="trail-end-left"></span><span class="trail-end">Личный кабинет</span><span class="trail-end-right"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/ .container-->
</div>
```

Comment: да, работает, но для больших экранов (кстати, в чем отличие первого и второго способа?). конкретно в данном случае для фразы `личный кабинет` картинки съезжают при экране меньше, чем 600, а как быть, если фраза длиннее? по медиазапросам так просто это не отследишь, если это вообще возможно..

Comment: @Вася обновил ответ посмотрите "На всю страницу"

Comment: да, отлично! только подправьте для более правильного ответа `min-width: 276px;` - все-таки длина может быть больше и `bottom: 0; transform: translate(-50%, 0);` по заданию просто было внизу расположить

Answer (score 2):

Хром и Сафари по разному рендерят шрифты, сафари например добавляет свои пиксели. поэтому нужно делать проверку с помощью js-а и добавлять класс, в котором делать фикс для маков:

```
<script>
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mac') > 0)
    $('body').addClass('mac-os');
</script>

<style>
.mac-os .selector {property:value;}
</style>
```

или использовать хак:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media {
.selector { property:value; } 
}}
```

Comment: спасибо. под `.selector` вы что имеете ввиду  - mad-breadcrumbs? или все те селекторы, которые со шрифтами и отступами? мне просто эта запись не очень-то понятна)

Comment: @Вася, да, это ваш класс `mad-breadcrumbs`